# How to get a byte array from a drawable resource ?

Tags: android, arrays, resources, drawable

I would like to get a byte array from an jpeg image located in my res/drawable file ?

Does anyone know how to do that please ?

Comment: I believe you can use solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable/36062748#36062748

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Get a bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) `decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources, int)`
Then either compress it to ByteArrayOutputStream() or copyPixelsToBuffer and get your array from the buffer.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Answer (score 11):

```
    Drawable drawable;

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG /* FileType */,
                        100 /* Ratio */, stream);
```

HTH !