# How to call getDrawable method

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am creating an image sharing app which uses a button to share images. I'm getting an `unable to resolve the required method error` in the code below:

```
public class ShareActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void button1Click()
    {
        BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable(button1);
        Bitmap mysharebmp = bm.getBitmap();
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                            mysharebmp, "MyImage", null);
```

On this line:

```
BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable(button1);ShareActivity
```

I am getting `The method getDrawable(Button) is undefined for the type ShareActivity`. Why might I be getting this error? The full code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955943/share-the-selected-image-only-in-android).

Comment: what is that you are doing. `getDrawable(button1);` did you look at the docs for the api?. Your question is not clear.

Comment: i want a button which can share my images to social apps, this is what i want to do sir

Comment: where is your images??

Comment: what you are doing is wrong. You already have the button. To share it to social apps like facebook. You need to look at their facebooksdk. The images i guess are stored in sdcard or in gallery. You will need to get the path of those images

Comment: the images are in `drawable` folder inside `res`.

Comment: @Raghunandan sir i am new to development, i don't know how to give location to images :(

Comment: this link may useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android?rq=1

Comment: store the images in external storage and get the path of those images. Google search you will find many exmaples

Comment: As a warning, do not insult people trying to help you. I've removed those comments.

Answer (score 3):

It's extremely unclear as to what you want to do here, and I suspect you're going to encounter a number of other problems with this code. But the reason that you're getting the error "getDrawable is undefined for ShareActivity" is because the `Activity` class does not have a `getDrawable` method.

Instead of calling `getDrawable`, you need to get the app resources and then retrieve the drawable. What you're looking for is:

```
BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_bitmap);
```

Where you have some image called "my_bitmap.png" in `/res/drawable/`.

**Edit Feb 7 2016**: This answer is no longer correct. [`Context#getDrawable(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable(int)) was added in API 21 (Lollipop) which was released in November 2014.
[Note that you probably shouldn't be using it anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29041466/1217087).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the image displayed inside the button the consider using the function defined inside the image button object.
I mean to say use button1.getDrawable()

Answer (score -2):

The getDrawable() method requires **id of the resource** and in this case you are passing Button. Try passing **R.id.button1**
Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29)

Comment: it still asking to create method for `getDrawable();`

Comment: Post the entire error-whatever it may be...
I assume you implemented the onClick(View v) method of View.OnClickListener()

Comment: -1 because you can not pass the button id in the `getDrawable`