# Share an image that is set as wallpaper in my app (error - file unknown file cannot send)

Tags: android, bluetooth, share, android-drawable

I am working on Wallpaper app, in which user can set wallpaper and share that wallpaper also via bluetooth, and other apps also.
I have used following to identify user selected wallpaper.

```
ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_preview);
imagePreview.setTag("a1");
```

And used `getTag()` in my another function to use that selected wallpaper.

To share the user selected image i have used following code

```
String mDrawableName = (String) imagePreview.getTag();
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackage.wallpaperapp/drawable/"+mDrawableName);
Log.d("here i got", imageUri.toString()); // here i got  android.resource://com.mypackage.wallpaperapp/drawable/a3
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share From"));
```

But i am getting the the error in device that " **file unknown file cannot send**",
Where am i wrong here?

I found in some stuff that i have to firstly save my image resource into storage and after that i can send my image.
But i dont know how can i save my image resource file into storage and send it to via different apps.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618432/3743093

In short: you can't pass an URI created with

`Uri uri = Uri.parse(String);`

to `shareIntent`, beacuse it lacks info like `TITLE` and `MIME_TYPE`.
That's because file type is unknown (missing) and throws this error.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(filename),
        values);
```

Hope this helps.