# Unable sharing image in android

Tags: android, android-sharing

I am new in android Java. I am trying to share an image in android application using Phonegap. I get new class "Share" as CordovaPlugin, code is follow...

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/www/sharethis.png");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Above code is not working, it showing like this ...

[image]

is think i cant get Exact image file location. My file location

[image]

I tried bellow code also, But not work,

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/assets/www/sharethis.png";
```

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android asset folder is private to your app so you can't share files from there directly. You need to copy the file from assets to a public directory in the filesystem and then send the share intent pointing to the public file. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android)