# Trying to share the image

Tags: android

I have an array of images, they are being displayed in an image view. I want to share any image i want out of them. I have written a code but it has some problem. The popup window appears but the image cannot be shared, it says failed to load image.

Here is my code:

```
private void shareImage() {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse((thumb[j]));
        try {
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    screenshotUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));

    }
```

And i am initializing this `shareImage()` in my onClickListener.

thumb is my string array.

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
private String[] thumb = new String[] {

            "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/seven-min_zpsdnohn4io.png",
            "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/one-min_zpsxdzul6kt.png" };
```

Comment: Can you post some example of the strings contained in thumb array?

Comment: Where do you want to share the image to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly share a remote image. Before share the image you need to download it in the local storage of the device. To download the image the simplest method is the `AsyncTask`.

This is a fast proof-of-concept, as you can see the image is downloaded in the cache directory and after that shared:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        findViewById(android.R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new ShareImageTask().execute("http://s.imgur.com/images/logo-1200-630.jpg");
            }
        });
    }

    private class ShareImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String url = urls[0];
            String path = null;

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                File outputDir = getExternalCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
                File outputFile = File.createTempFile("share_image", ".png", outputDir);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();

                path = outputFile.getPath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                path = null;
            }

            return path;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
                Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, "Error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            share(result);
        }
    }

    private void share(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add these two permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For example in your code you can change your `shareImage` method to this:

```
private void shareImage() {
    new ShareImageTask().execute(thumb[j]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i think this might solve my problem, but i am trying to fix it for my case and i am failing

Comment: could yo please help me in that i can share my code to you

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example for your case. If you want to share the code you should update your answer, so every users of SO can see it and maybe help you. If you have other doubts, write a comment or edit your question, don't open other questions.

Comment: Unfortunately "didn't work" is not enough to allow me to help you.  What does not work? There is an error? Can you post logcat? Update your question with relevant code so i can see what you doing. thanks

Comment: Here is my full source code, sharing you the link as it wont get copied here, http://paste.ofcode.org/39XF88fT6vsX4wFnYMaPNk4.  I am executing the sharing in swipe gesture, i have added comments to save your time.

Comment: With a fast look there is an error in line 484, it should be `new ShareImageTask().execute(thumb[j]);` without double quote

Comment: You are awesome man, Its working though its a bit slow and hanging