# Android share text and image on linkedIn using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api

Here I'm trying to send image with text on `LinkedIn` as post as:

```
Intent linkedinIntent;
            String text1 = "...kaLis...";
            linkedinIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri path = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(),
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.logo), null, null));
            linkedinIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
            linkedinIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text1);
            linkedinIntent.setType("image/*");
            // linkedinIntent.setType("text/plain");
            boolean linkedinAppFound = false;
            List<ResolveInfo> matches2 = activity.getPackageManager()
                    .queryIntentActivities(linkedinIntent, 0);

            for (ResolveInfo info : matches2) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith(
                        "com.linkedin")) {
                    linkedinIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    linkedinAppFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (linkedinAppFound) {
                activity.startActivity(linkedinIntent);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "LinkedIn app not Insatlled in your mobile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

But this code is enable to send only a thing at a time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android

Comment: I can also post image. But I want to post both simultaneously.

Comment: did you try the linkedin SDK ?

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue ?