# Share an image taken from camera to image view

Tags: android, android-camera

Hello I'm new to android studio I have built an app when you take a photo from the camera app see it in an ImageView and share it

I have made a share button:

```
case R.id.shrbtn:
  startshare();
  break;
```

the share button go to this method to start sharing the photo 
I have added internet permission and the button don't do anything:

```
private void startshare() {
  Bitmap bmp=viewToBitmap(Image,Image.getWidth(),Image.getHeight());
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("image/*");
  Uri phototUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp)));
  shareIntent.setData(phototUri);
  shareIntent.putExtra(shareIntent.EXTRA_STREAM,phototUri);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));
}
```

can anyone tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Send it by an intent and get it from startActivityForResult() method.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Z6k7X2vfhk) tutorial explains it well

Comment: i already have that method but for the button that set the image as wallpaper                         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            Image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like an issue regarding the button callback itself. Have you make sure that the method have been called? Maybe you should set breakpoints to identify the issue?

Maybe you should take a look here (as your share intent looks wrong): https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662164/6268503

Comment: i forgot to set the setOnClickListener i set it test the app on my tablet and a pop up show with this no app can perform this action here is my code again      Bitmap bmp=viewToBitmap(Image,Image.getWidth(),Image.getHeight());
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");

        Uri phototUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp)));
        shareIntent.setData(phototUri);
        shareIntent.putExtra(shareIntent.EXTRA_STREAM,phototUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));