# share image from application folder

Tags: java, android

I want share image from on `click` of `button`

`Java` code

```
public void share(View v)
{
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    Uri a=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.drawable.pic); 
    Log.i("imageUri",""+imageUri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,a);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share Image"));
}
```

by this code is not working , what changes should i do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use "Share image using" sharing Intent to share images in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**First** You need to add permission **`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Note :** for `Marshmallow` and above version You need **[Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)** of **`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`** and Here is good example of **[Runtime Permission for EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/7073808)**

Then use following code to share your Image

```
Bitmap b =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pic);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
String path =  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    b, "Title", null);
Uri a=  Uri.parse(path);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, a);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the complement sir, @NileshRathod. I am learning from you Great Developers

Comment: Graet.. keep it up

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to share image:

**NOTE:** you have to add `WRITE/READ EXTERNAL STORAGE` permission in `Menifest` file to do this:

```
           Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    mBitmap, "Image Description", null);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Log.d("imageUri", "imageUriIs" + uri);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMSG);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "TITLE");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "APPNAME"));
```