# How to share bytes ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, byte

I've just wanted share byte array but when I used "EXTRA_STREAM" it didn't work.
Please help me.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            if (attachBytes != null) {

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, byteArray);
                intent.setType(sharingMessageType + "/*");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }

            return intent;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use "Share image using" sharing Intent to share images in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android)

Comment: What is `attachBytes`? Show decent code please.

Comment: it is a byte array

Comment: Not duplicate it is sharing byte array, your question is sharing uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) states that its value is:

> **A `content:` URI** holding a stream of data associated with the `Intent`, used with `ACTION_SEND` to supply the data being sent.

(emphasis added)

So, the value for your `EXTRA_STREAM` needs to be a `Uri` with a `content` scheme that points to the data that you wish to share. For example, you could use `FileProvider` to share a file that contains the data that you wish to share.

Regardless, you cannot directly put a `byte[]` as the value of `EXTRA_STREAM` and expect it to work with arbitrary apps. The developers of the other apps will be expecting a `Uri` with a `content` scheme and will crash when trying to use your `byte[]`, probably with a `ClassCastException`.