# Sharing image to applock vault using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I have been working on a project on android gallery application. I have implemented image sharing using intents which is working fine with all apps images are being shared there but **when it comes sharing images to AppLock to store them into vault it is not working**.

When I share image to AppLock the activity opens and closes without showing anything. I am using the following code to share images.

```
private Intent createShareIntent()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    File image=new File(currentImageUri.getPath());
    Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".GenericFileProvider",image);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    return intent;
}
```

I have almost searched everywhere for this but could not find any help.

Comment: are you getting any error ??

Comment: no there are no errors applock activity simply opens and closes without showing anything.

Comment: You can refer to this link, might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android

Comment: This method wouldn't work because if is exposing file:/ uri to external apps which doesn't work after Android M. FileProvider had to be used.