# java.lang.NullPointerException occur when using Compressor library

Tags: android, image-processing, nullpointerexception, android-image, image-compression

I'm having trouble compressing image using compressor library(https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor)
when I try compressing using Android-Image-Cropper(https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) Everything works well,
but when I use

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

The error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

occure

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the image URI in the intent so it is giving `NullPointerException`

Try this:

```
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

This code excerpt is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662164/6549598).