# How do I make a slide up fragment for share button?

Tags: android, android-animation, fragment-animation

Can anyone suggest me from where should I start to make a slide up animation of fragment when user clicks on share button? Fragment will contain screenshot of the current view and the app where we can share. Here's a example from ixigo app after clicking on share button.
[After Click on share button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e7Lj.jpg)

[Sliding up to the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpTeL.jpg)

Suggest some topics, sample of code or libraries which can help me create something like this.

Comment: you can share an image with intents, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android;

Comment: you can use BottomSheetBehavior https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior

Comment: You can make custom modal bottom sheet. Please refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfpRL2K1hJk