# How to share image from viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, share-intent

GalleryAdapter class

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> images;
    protected PhotoListener photoListener;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> images, PhotoListener photoListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.photoListener = photoListener;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String image = images.get(position);
        int pos = position;

        Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.image);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                photoListener.onPhotoClick(image, pos);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }


    }
    public interface PhotoListener {

        void onPhotoClick(String path, int position);
    }
}
```

My List images is the list of query absolute path of image in android studio
My screen to show image is viewpager. I want to share an image when I click the share button. But I don't know how to do that. It doesn't have a lot of docs about share viewpager.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You must be implementing the PhotoListener in your Activity or Fragment where you are showing this view-pager and passing the same listener to your adapter's constructor somewhat like below:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PhotoListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    GalleryAdapter adapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, new String[]{},this);
    
}

@Override
public void onPhotoClick(String path, int position) {
    // compose photo sharing intent here and start activity with that intent
}
```

}

Using above implementation, you can compose the photo-sharing intent as mentioned here: [How to use "Share image using" sharing Intent to share images in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android)