# reading resource as InputStream in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some android project and I am trying to read some file from the "res/drawable-xhdpi" directory so  I put

```
InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.my_btn); //my_btn is inside drawable-xhdpi directory
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I get

```
error opening trace file: No such file or directory
```

How can I deal with this issue. I tried to read this directly from `FileInputStream` with an absolute path, then I realized that the root from which the files are fetched is the root of the `JVM` so I still got the same `No such file or directory`error message

Update :

I added an `assets` directory in side `src/main`, then I put `my_btn.png` inside it then I call inside my `MainActivity` class

```
InputStream is = null;

        try {

            is = getAssets().open("my_btn.png");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I still get the same error

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve this way? This is not how you use drawable resources. `openRawResource()` is for raw resources, not drawable resources.

Comment: I am just trying to test and I take a picture and send it to `Parse`

Comment: that is being more complex than it should, probably because the base approach for doing it is wrong. So as a suggestion, edit your question telling us what you want to achieve, so we can find a more suitable answer.

Answer (score 3):

The drawable will be fetched from `"res/drawable-xhdpi"` only if you are running the app on an `xhdpi` device. Else it will try to fetch the drawable from the corresponding drawable folder according to the screen and if it is not there, you will get the same error as above. If you are not sure which screen size you are using the best work around is to create a directory named `"drawable"` inside the res folder(ie, `"res/drawable"`) and then add `my_btn` into the newly created `"drawable"` folder. Then it will fetch the image from the new folder regardless of the screen size.

**EDIT**

You are using the raw folder, not the resource folder. `openRawResource` reads from the raw folder. Use the following code to get a drawable and convert it to input stream(You will have to surround with try-catch).

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_btn);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //use the compression format of your need
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
```

Comment: I did what you say, I added some picture to a drawable folder and I  still get the same message !!

Comment: Wait. After reading the comment under your question, I noticed that you are doing something terribly wrong. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Updated. Please check and tell me if it helped. :)

Comment: That's fairly memory intensive for the use case.

Comment: Just answered his question. His question was about getting a drawable to an inputstream.

Comment: Ah ok, I am completely sorry, this error was thrown from another resource missing - sorry again

Comment: And what if you don't want to recompress it but want the orginal file?

Answer (score 2):

_pm.iconStream = getResources().openRawResource(+ R.drawable.pdf_icon);

Answer (score 1):

> I am just trying to test and I take a picture and send it to Parse

Put your test image somewhere either in `res/raw/` (then, use your existing code, with `R.raw.whatever_you_call_the_image`) or in `assets/` (then, use `getAssets().open()` with a relative path within `assets/` to your image).

Comment: I tried to add `assets/` directory to the `res` folder than I put `getAssets().open("my_btn")` and I still get the same message

Comment: @user1611830: You forgot the file extension. With assets, you use the full filename with the extension.

Comment: sorry I meant I put the right extension. By the way , when I put `Log.d("TAG", Arrays.toString(getAssets().list(".")));` I get an empty array

Comment: @user1611830: Since you have no files named `.`, that is not surprising. This is not a directory; it is entries in a ZIP-style archive (the APK).

Comment: @user1611830 Its not to the res folder that you have to add the assets directory. First of all you need to add it in src>main(Since you are using android studio). And secondly don't forget the extension.

Comment: @user1611830: Yes, Harikrishan is correct -- I missed that in your original comment. `assets/` is a peer to `res/`, not a child of `res/`.

Comment: ok so I moved the `assets` folder inside `src/main` and I put `is = getAssets().open("btn_fb.png");` (`is` is declared as `InputStream is`) but I still get the same message

Comment: @user1611830: Here is a sample project that demonstrates reading a file from `assets/` (in this case, to copy it to a local file, to then be served by `FileProvider`): https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider

Comment: sorry I don't want to bother, I have just updated my post. I followed exactly what you said, I rebuild the project but it still doesn't work. Is there a configuration I missed when adding the assets folder ?

Comment: @user1611830: From what I can see, that should be OK. Compare what you have with the sample project's code for accessing the asset, for the sample that I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: Ah ok, I am completely sorry, this error was thrown from another resource missing - sorry again

Comment: Is it the answer actual, will approach in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36062748/241986 work?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov: I have no idea if it works. I would not use it.