# Android: Tweet composer and image

Tags: android, twitter

I am working on **TweetComposer** from *Twitter Kit*. As far as I know, TweetComposer only provides an image URI.

How can I use this URI get images into a **Drawable** or **Asset**?

Comment: Thanks Andy for correcting my question, I was so rushed at that time so didn't check grammar and meaning, just tried to raised the question before backing home. In addition, I gave some tries on getting Uri from Drawable but not successful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still actual but anyway...
Create `Bitmap` file from your drawable resource with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`, then save it to some temporary file is some way like this:

```
String filename = "temp_image.png";
FileOutputStream fos;

fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

Then use `Uri.fromFile()` to get `Uri`.

Comment: Context.MODE_PRIVATE will prevent any other application from accessing the file, including the Twitter application. Rather, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE should be used (although it was depreciated in API 17), but Google strongly cautions against this due to security concerns: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE