# Opening message app with image attached to it

Tags: android

I am trying to build a messaging app activity. I want to open the attached image in the messaging app but my messaging app is stopping. I have set all the required permissions. The following is my code:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.works.vipul.imageinmms/"R.drawable.images);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
    sendIntent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Send"));
```

Comment: looks like uri is wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable

Comment: The Uri is right as its showing image it is suppose to represent in the side bar in android studio

Comment: "android.resource://com.works.vipul.imageinmms/drawable/images"   <-------Use that and make sure its a png

Comment: Is that your actual code? I would expect it to be confused by the `"android.resource://com.works.vipul.imageinmms/"R.drawable.images` with the `R.drawable.images`

Comment: I used the above code. Its a png and it still gave me the same problem.

Comment: PLEASE HELP  MATES. ITS NOT WORKING

Answer (score 1):

```
com.works.vipul.imageinmms/" + R.drawable.images);
```

Add the "+". If that doesn't work, post a stack trace of the crash.