# Saving image from imageview to Drawable and vice versa

Tags: java, android, uri, android-imageview, android-drawable

I want to save my current `ImageView` image to `Drawable` and later on retrieve that image from the `Drawable` and render it to `ImageView`. Has anyone faced a similar problem?

This is my code so far to retrieve the image from `Drawable` but it's not working...

```
Drawable d = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(d));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit. You write that "it's not working", could you [edit] your question to tell us what happens when you try this? If there is anything interesting in the LogCat, then please add that as well. BTW, asking if people have experienced the same makes it sound a bit like a poll; you may want to avoid that phrase on Stack Overflow, as asking for opinions/polling is off-topic here. Good luck, hope you'll get an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set image by URI. Use this instead:

```
mImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: I will try it now and then will tell you :)

Comment: Now second part is how to save my imageview to drawable ??

Comment: You can't do that. And why would you do that? Drawable folder is for manual use.

Comment: Basically i want to save my imageview image to drawable and then i want to take my image uri and pass it to android default cropping intent to perform cropping on it ...

Comment: You cannot modify res/drawable at runtime. Here is what you can do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable