# Android - Resources - How to identify drawable by uri?

Tags: android, resources

I have looking on a few decompiled app and don't understand how to locate image in resources by uri. For example, I have uri:

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

So what I need to do? Open `res` folder and look in each folder beginning from `drawable` to find icon.png? Thanks

Comment: i think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you look in the `res/drawable` folder with a file name matching exactly the text following `@drawable/`. In this case `icon`.

The extension could be any image format - `jpg`, `png`, `bmp` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just press **ctrl button** along with just do **left click** from the mouse on the `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` and then android studio will identify it for you.
or manually you can follow the steps suggested by @AndroidMechanic