# Drawable to data url in android

Tags: android, android-drawable, data-url

I have a Drawable generated by a library,it makes round image with letter inside.

But in the view that I have to insert, accepts only url, and I need to convert this drawable to a url, but I don't know how to do it.

The Drable looks like:

```
TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                            .buildRound(mConnection.getUser().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(), ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),mConnection.getContactStatus(mcontact).getColor()));;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Data URL is a misspelling of Data URI - a URI which represents the resource itself, rather than the location of the resource.

Comment: Then, is possible to do this? I mean, what i need to send is:
`  textMessage.setAvatarUrl(String url);`

Comment: From an image stored in your drawable folder you can get the URI by using some of the methods explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable . However i don't know if it's possible the get an URI from a local  drawable variable.

Answer (score 2):

> But in the view that I have to insert, accepts only url

Stop using that `View` and switch to another one that accepts a `Drawable`.

> I need to convert this drawable to a url

If you want to waste the user's RAM, CPU, and battery, you can draw the `Drawable` to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`, write that `Bitmap` out to a file (e.g., PNG) using `compress()`, then try using a `file:///` `URL`.

Your question title suggests using a `data:` `URL`. Unless the documentation for this unidentified `View` specifically claims that the `View` supports the `data` scheme, most likely it does not.