# Set an image if Uri is empty

Tags: android, uri

I want to set an image to the Uri if the Uri is empty, this is what I did:

```
if (imageUri == null)
{
    imageUri = imageUri.parse(String.valueOf(R.drawable.no_image_available));
}
```

It does not give any error but it doesn't work, is there any other way I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I found some solutions in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable hope it works :)

Comment: use: `Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/R.drawable.no_image_available");
        imageview.setImageURI(uri);`

Comment: @RustFisher thanks, It did help.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Wow, it just became simple, thanks.

Comment: @Zack i have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap yourImageNotFoundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.no_image_available);
if (imageUri == null){

yourImage.setImageBitmap(yourImageNotFoundBitmap);

}
```

Comment: Why not setting the image from resource directly? Bitmaps are costlier for memory. Nice answer, but handling the change directly will make it better

Comment: @MohammedAtif, how can I achieve that?

Comment: `yourImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_available);` thats it

Comment: @MohammedAtif, Wow.. amazing, it works fine...Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead you can use glide library. If imageUrl is there then it will show otherwise it will take placeHolder image.


    Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .dontTransform()
            .placeholder(placeholder)
            .into(imageView);


http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/circular-images-glide-library-android/#.WNiXPxKGNPN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check that Empty URI is not equal to followUri, this check includes check by null:

```
 if (!Uri.EMPTY.equals(followUri)) {
        //handle followUri
 }
```

Comment: What do I need to have between the braces?

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
imageUri = imageUri.parse(String.valueOf(R.drawable.no_image_available));
```

will not give you a valid `Uri`.

There is Much more easier option:

**option 1**

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/R.drawable.no_image_available"); 
imageview.setImageURI(uri);  //set the uri
```

**OR**   use:

```
if (imageUri == null)
{
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_available);
}
```