# android Resolve URI of an image

Tags: android, url, uri

I found some block of code online,where the main aim of the snippet is to get image URI which is inside the res folder but when i changed the code to my apps path....the app crashes! I know the solution is simple n tricky,so please help me
here is the method

```
 public static SkyBox getSkyBox1() {
    try {
        return new SkyBox(new URI[]{
                URI.create("com.habie.a3d_model/res/drawable/right.png"),
                URI.create("com.habie.a3d_model/res/drawable/left.png"),
                URI.create("com.habie.a3d_modelres/drawable/top.png"),
                URI.create("com.habie.a3d_model/res/drawable/bottom.png"),
                URI.create("com.habie.a3d_model/res/drawable/front.png"),
                URI.create("com.habie.a3d_model/res/drawable/back.png")});



    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

these are the images i want to use them....

Answer (score 1):

Your URI doesn't have any scheme defined. Try changing to:

```
URI.create("android.resource://com.habie.a3d_model/res/drawable/right.png")
```

Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6606163/14241710

Comment: that would bre cool! But URI doesnt have .parse method i guess..

Comment: that would bre cool! But URI doesnt have .parse method i guess..

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you are using the `java.net.URI`. The reference code is for `android.net.Uri`.
Just replace parse with create and it should work.
Or maybe you can use the `android.net.Uri`