# Copy a image from res directory

Tags: android

I have stored some images in res folder of my app. But the user can download this image to their sdcard using the download option. How can I copy the image in res folder to sdcard. Can anyone help me.

Comment: either use screen capture code or put the image in assest folder

Comment: +1, ya, as per ingsaurabh suggested put image in asset folder or load image in activity then capture screen but it is ugliest way, just put image in asset and copy it to sdcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
    if (isSdPresent()) { // to check is sdcard mounted
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
            bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            Bitmap bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "FolderName";
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(extStorageDirectory);
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            File file = new File(wallpaperDirectory,"icon.png");
                     //to get resource name getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.icon);

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            }
            } else {

            }
```

to check SDCard

```
public boolean isSdPresent() {
        return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829469/how-to-get-a-byte-array-from-a-drawable-ressource) getting a stream from your image and posting it to the user to download...