# How to convert Xamarin.Forms.Image to byte array or memory stream

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

This question may be easy but I could not found answer on internet.

I have icon.png in Resource/drawable folder in Droid   project. I want to convert this image into byte array.

I know the conversion from memory stream to byte array but I could not find a way to convert image to byte array or memorystream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829469/how-to-get-a-byte-array-from-a-drawable-resource)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a byte array from a drawable resource ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829469/how-to-get-a-byte-array-from-a-drawable-resource)

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Demitrian. But I want to convert image in xamarin.forms. Is it possible in xamarin.forms ??